# How to get rid of margin gaps between body columns in HTML (used css template but edited myself a lot)

Tags: html, css, web

Used a css template and edited, now between the 3 columns there is a small margin gap which id like to get rid of. tried readjusting the columun sizes but the margin gap still exists. Is there a more simple way I could have achieved the same page, if so how?? Yes im a newbie :P

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}


/* Style the header */

.header {
  background-color: #F1C40F;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Style the footer */

.footer {
  background-color: #F1C40F;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Create three unequal columns that floats next to each other */
  .column {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  /* top, middle and bottom column */
  .columntopmiddlebottom {
    width: 30%;
  }
  /* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other 
    instead of next to each other */
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column.side,
    .column.middle {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  .auto-style2 {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.auto-style2 {
  margin-top: 31px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="row" style="height: 717px">
  <div class="columntopmiddlebottom" style="background-color:#F7DC6F; 
    style=" height: 211px>
    <h2>People</h2>
    <p style="height: 214px">1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="columntopmiddlebottom" style="background-color:#F7DC6F; 
     style=" height: 212px>
    <h2 style="height: 21px">2</h2>
    <p style="height: 171px">info</p>
  </div>

  <div class="columntopmiddlebottom" style="background-color:#F7DC6F; 
     style=" height: 212px>
    <h2 style="height: 37px">3</h2>
    <p style="height: 193px">info</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Gaps under and above each column appears, dont want the gaps.

Comment: take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing , also give a reset to margin:0; to h2 meanwhile reading

Comment: Have you considered *not* investing time in learning a framework that uses old - and arguably obsolete - techniques, and instead using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) or [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.columntopmiddlebottom * {
    margin-block-start: 0;
    margin-block-end: 0;
}
```

A usefull trick when writing CSS is using the browsers development tools:
In Google when you right click on an element and press Inspect you can see which CSS is on that element. If you can't find the problem you are looking for you can try pressing CTRL + SHIFT + C and go over the elements to find your problem.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

> The top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the individual margins (or just one of them, if they are equal), a behavior known as margin collapsing. Note that the margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements never collapse.

reset margin to hn and p .

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2,
p {
  margin: 0;/* reset margin to avoid collapsing . Note , padding or border on the parent will keep margin inside*/
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}


/* Style the header */

.header {
  background-color: #F1C40F;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Style the footer */

.footer {
  background-color: #F1C40F;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Create three unequal columns that floats next to each other */
  .column {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  /* top, middle and bottom column */
  .columntopmiddlebottom {
    width: 30%;
  }
  /* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other 
    instead of next to each other */
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column.side,
    .column.middle {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  .auto-style2 {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.auto-style2 {
  margin-top: 31px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="row" style="height: 717px">
  <div class="columntopmiddlebottom" style="background-color:#F7DC6F; 
    style=" height: 211px>
    <h2>People</h2>
    <p style="height: 214px">1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="columntopmiddlebottom" style="background-color:#F7DC6F; 
     style=" height: 212px>
    <h2 style="height: 21px">2</h2>
    <p style="height: 171px">info</p>
  </div>

  <div class="columntopmiddlebottom" style="background-color:#F7DC6F; 
     style=" height: 212px>
    <h2 style="height: 37px">3</h2>
    <p style="height: 193px">info</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/  in css to remove margin and padding for element

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: #F1C40F;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
.one {
  background-color: #F7DC6F;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
.two {
  background-color: #F1C40F;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
.three {
  background-color: #F7DC6F;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
.four {
  background-color: #F1C40F;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
footer{
  background-color: #F7DC6F;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum eum minus aliquam dolorum sit molestiae architecto.</p>
  </header>
  <section class="one">
    <h2>Section One</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum eum minus aliquam dolorum sit molestiae architecto.</p>
  </section>
  <div class="two">
    <h2>Gallery</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum eum minus aliquam dolorum sit molestiae architecto.</p>
  </div>
  <article class="three">
    <h2>News</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum eum minus aliquam dolorum sit molestiae architecto.</p>
  </article>
  <aside class="four">
    <h2>Aside NavBar</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum eum minus aliquam dolorum sit molestiae architecto.</p>
  </aside>
  <footer >
    <h2>Aside NavBar</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum eum minus aliquam dolorum sit molestiae architecto.</p>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple version using Flexbox.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
}
.header {
 background-color: #F1C40F;
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}
.row {
 background-color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}
.column {
 flex-grow: 1;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color:#F7DC6F;
 height: 200px
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 .row {
  flex-direction: column;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 <h1>Header</h1>
 <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="column">
  <h2>People</h2>
  <p>1</p>
 </div>

 <div class="column">
  <h2>2</h2>
  <p>info</p>
 </div>

 <div class="column">
  <h2>3</h2>
  <p>info</p>
 </div>
</div>
```